# Is there a way to get hierarchical payload data in a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Products**:

```
ItemId   ItemName   ParentId    payload
----------------------------------------
    1    Food       null        payload1
    2    Drinks     null        payload2
    3    Other      null        payload3
    4    Fruits       1         payload4
    5    Vegetables   1         payload5
    6    Carrots      3         payload6
    7    Carrots      5         payload7
```

**Customer orders**:

```
CustId   ParentItemName   ItemName
----------------------------------
  1      Food             Carrots
```

**The Issue:**

```
select *, (???) from CustomerOrders
```

`???` = Is there a way to obtain `'payload7'` in a subquery? Note the identical value of `'Carrots'` in `payload6`, but I'm given the parent item `'food'` so I know which is which. Hope this make sense.

**Rules:**

1. Joins not available.
2. Hierarchy 3-deep max
3. Must happen in a sub-query

Comment: You'll have to explain more about how you get to `payload7` and not `payload6` when your input is `food` as  parent item. Both Fruits and Vegetables have Food as a parent, therefore Carrots is a grandchild of Food through both branches making `payload6` and `payload7` equally viable by my eyes.

Comment: there's a mistake, sorry about that payload 6 is suppose to have parent other

Comment: Ah! ok. In that case, what happens if `Fruits` has more than one child (like besides Carrots)? Would you want both, or is there something special about carrots?

Comment: In this example, the one customer order specifies `Food` and `Carrots` wouldn't there only be one possible payload regardless if fruit or vegetables have more children?

Comment: I see! So the input is `food` as the parent and `carrots` as the child and you want the related payload. This makes sense now.

Comment: Correct, thanks for your patience

Comment: Why would JOINs not be available?   Doing this without any kind of JOIN (such as the kind you would find in a recursive CTE) is going to have performance that is beyond terrible.

Comment: I guess if the join could somehow be in the subquery, not sure. But I have to work inside the constraints of a subquery.

Comment: Why are you writing it as a sub-query? Correlated sub-queries are usually the worst technique to use.

Comment: Inherited this scenario

Comment: Is there a (practical) limit to the depth of the hierarchy? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: there's a 3 deep limit to the hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

What you will need here is a recursive CTE. This is a CTE that refers back to itself by way of a UNION. You give it a starting point (like all products that have a NULL parent) as a seed, then after the UNION you refer back to the CTE and join it back to the table. It will then iterate until the join fails.

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    --recursive seed (starting point of recursive query)
    SELECT
        ItemId,
        ItemId as RootParentId, --capture this starting point
        payload,
        0 as depth, --capture how deep we go into the hierarchy
        CAST(itemid AS VARCHAR(20)) as path --capture the path from the parent all the way down
    FROM products
    WHERE parentID IS NULL --Start at the top of the hierarchy

    --recursive term (the part executed over and over again)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        products.ItemId,
        recCTE.RootParentId,
        products.payload,
        depth + 1 as depth,
        CAST(recCTE.ItemId AS VARCHAR(20)) + '>' + CAST(products.ItemId AS VARCHAR(20))     
    FROM recCTE --refers to itself
        INNER JOIN products on reccte.ItemId = products.ParentID
    WHERE depth < 10 --just in case we get into a loop
)

--Now we can select from the results:
SELECT payload FROM recCTE where ItemID = 7 and RootPArentID = 1 --carrots and food;
```

Here I only captured the ids from the Products table, but you could add in your ItemNames as well. This is a very useful type of query once you get your head wrapped around it.

IF you are incorporating this into a bigger query then it would look something like:

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    --recursive seed (starting point of recursive query)
    SELECT
        ItemId,
        ItemId as RootParentId --capture this starting point,
        payload,
        0 as depth, --capture how deep we go into the hierarchy
        CAST(itemid AS VARCHAR(20)) as path --capture the path from the parent all the way down
    FROM products
    WHERE parentID IS NULL --Start at the top of the hierarchy

    --recursive term (the part executed over and over again)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        products.ItemId,
        recCTE.RootParentId,
        products.payload,
        depth + 1 as depth,
        recCTE.ItemId + '>' + products.ItemId       
    FROM recCTE --refers to itself
        INNER JOIN products on reccte.ItemId = products.ParentID
    WHERE depth < 10 --just in case we get into a loop
)

SELECT sometable.somefield, subquery.payload
FROM sometable
    INNER JOIN recCTE as subquery ON sometable.productid = subquery.itemid and sometable.parentid = subquery.RootParentID;
```

So the CTE just hangs out at the top and becomes much like a "Subquery" which is all a CTE really is.

Comment: the with () is done before your query and the last select part can be done from within the subquery.

Comment: I've added an attempt at an example of how this might work as a subquery (a CTE and a subquery are the same thing, the only difference is where you  write the SQL that defines it)

Comment: @jnevill, you commented out your comma after 2nd field in anchor query.  additionally I think you'll have an error on the itemID + '>' +... on the hierachy. http://rextester.com/UNJ25652

Comment: Fixed the comma in the top query and added some casts in there in case SQL Server doesn't automagically cast those things.